# PHP:How to find most left node on binary tree?

Tags: php, laravel, tree, binary

Say I have this tree:

```
         root
       /      \
      1        2
    /   \     /
   3     4   5
        /
       6
      /  \
     8    7
    /      \
   9       12
  /
10
  \
  11
```

I want to select `root`, then `left`, the result will be `3`. If `right`, it will be `2`.

If I select `6`, then the left will be `10`, right will be `12`.

I have been using this https://packagist.org/packages/kalnoy/nestedset. For now I have been using recursive from top to bottom to find (querying from database to find next left child), but it is not efficient, as the tree will become bigger.

I have tried using this (to find left):

```
if (!$child = self::where('parent_id', $this->id)->where('position', 'left')->first()) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!$grandChild = $child->leftChild()) {
            return $child;
        }

        $outerLeftChild = $child->descendants()->where('position', 'left')->whereIsLeaf()->get();

        if (count($outerLeftChild) <= 0) {
            $outerLeftChild = $child->descendants()->where('position', 'left')->hasChildren()->get();
            if (count($outerLeftChild) <= 0) {
                return $child;
            }
        }

        return $outerLeftChild->sortBy('_lft')->last();
```

but sometimes, it will find the wrong node, like if I select root, it might select `10` instead of `3`, `_lft` comes from the package I have no idea what it actually does.

I have `level`, `position` (left or right), and `parent_id` for each node data. Each node will only have 2 nodes max (left & right), but it can also one node or nothing at all.

Can anyone at least tell me the theory for this solution?

Comment: For left direction: while (node has left child) node = left child

Comment: @Olivier isn't that same as loop, wouldn't it be slow if i kept querying on database?

Comment: You never said there was a database. Well, one way or another, you will need to fetch nodes to inspect them, you can't avoid that.

Comment: If the tree is not too large, you could fetch it entirely in one query and traverse it locally.

Comment: @Olivier the tree will become large, potentially hundreds of levels, and I edited the question to include query loop from database

Comment: A solution would be to write a stored procedure.